# 8th Street, Street No.8 or Street 8?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, forms-of-address

In my country, there're a lot of street name like "Number 8", "Number 12",...etc

How to write it in English? I usually see something like "8th Street" or "Street No.8", but I don't know the difference.

Can you give me some information about it?
Thank you!

Comment: "Street No. 8" is definitely correct, "Street 8" is less specific, more colloquial. "8th Street" can be relative instead of a specific street. Eg: "After turning right, turn left onto the 8th street you pass across".

Comment: Numbered streets are almost unknown in the UK where I live, but New York famously has _Fifth Avenue, 59th Street Bridge_ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This will kind of depend on what you are trying to do. In the US, street names such as "Eighth Street" or "8th Street" are common. "Street No. 8" or "Street 8" are not (both sound like you're drawing the plans and haven't come up with names yet). Generally though, you will want to write an address so that a letter addressed to you gets delivered by the local mail carrier.

Comment: Yes, you should check with the mail authority/company how to address. If sending mail internationally, there may be different rules, although it is still possible to put the majority of the address in the destination langauge/format, and the country name underneath in the language of the sender.

Answer (score 2):

I would treat street names as "names" and leave them untranslated. The main purpose of street names is to identify locations to people who know the city, as part of addresses.  Similar to how we don't translate personal names, it is acceptable not to translate place names.  Hence "Đường 8"  (if my Vietnamese is correct)  You may allow "Đường 8 street" (even if it is redundant).

If you desire to fully translate, then "8th Street" is possible.